# How to setup Cloudflare on AWS hosted website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, cloudflare

I'm currently using `AWS EC2`, `S3` and `RDS` for my website, and all the media is stored in `S3`.

If I would like to use Cloudflare for the entire website, should I just install regularly (where it will 'pull' and cache everything) or I should do this step or do both?

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-Cloudflare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-

Answer (score 1):

Though you can achieve this through **Amazon** [CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) Servies which offers the same functionality as that of `Cloudflare` and you do not need to configure additional things. But it does not specializes only on CDN. So You can safely use `Cloudflare` as they are specialized in Web Security.

> And it is always recommended to follow the guidelines [Cloudflare setup](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-Cloudflare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-).

***Edit:***
In addition to `Cloudfront`, if you wish you may also use [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) & [AWS Shield](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/) for security for the same reason you wish to use cloudflare.